# GCP: Compute Engine Default Service Account missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, service-accounts, google-iam

I tried to deploy an OpenVPN Access Server to Google Compute Engines and received the following error message:

```
openvpn-access-server-1-vm: {"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"EXTERNAL_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","ResourceErrorMessage":"The resource 'PROJECT_ID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found."}
```

PROJECT_ID is just a placeholder for my own PROJECT_ID.

In the cloud console, I can't find the "compute engine default service account" (I think, I accidentally deleted it last year). In the log files, I found in 2020 it's ACCOUNT_ID, so I tried to undelete it with the following command:

```
gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete ACCOUNT_ID
```

I had no success, I received:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.iam.service-accounts.undelete) NOT_FOUND: Not found; Not found AccountDataType for <numeric_id>
```

<numeric_id> was a 12-digit number.

I tried to disable and enable compute service to restore the default service account, but it wasn't successful, I received:

```
response:
'@type': type.googleapis.com/google.iam.admin.v1.ServiceAccount
serviceName: iam.googleapis.com
status:
code: 6
message: ALREADY_EXISTS
receiveTimestamp: '2021-08-05T06:45:55.798772716Z'
```

Because of this error, I tried to delete it, but this didn't work too.

Now I don't know what to do, to get the default service account back.
Is it still existing or not?
Why isn't it working?

Keep in mind, I'm talking about PROJECT_ID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com.
service-PROJECT_ID@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com is existing and recreated each time I disable and enable the Compute Engine API again.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Service Account was deleted an year ago it cannot be undeleted using the following command,

```
gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete ACCOUNT_ID
```

This only works for Service Accounts deleted fewer than 30 days ago. [Undeleting a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting) for more information.

Instead, we can [create a new Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) and [grant](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-console) an  ‘Editor’ role to it. As a Default Compute Engine Service Account has the same role by default. [Compute Engine default service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#default_service_account) for more information.

Now, we can create a new Compute Engine VM using the new Service Account. [Setting up a new instance to run as a service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#using) for more information.

If we already have a running VM and the Service Account got deleted, As @John Hanley suggested, we can edit the VM instance in the Google Cloud Console and assign the new Service Account to the instance. [Changing the service account and access scopes for an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) for more information.

To set the new Service Account as the Compute Engine Default Service Account on the project, we can use the following [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/project-info/set-default-service-account),

```
gcloud alpha compute project-info set-default-service-account
```

But since the command is in the ‘alpha’ [launch stage](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages), it is not available for everyone.

Another workaround would be creating a new project and deploying our instance there.

Comment: You can edit the VM instance in the Google Cloud Console and assign the new service account to the instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the good explanantion and for the command to set a new service account as default service account. But, as yout mentioned, I don't have access to the alpha command.

I want to deploy the [OpenVPN access server](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/google-cloud-platform-byol-instance-quick-start-guide): is there a possibility to define the service account to use (the new one, i have created)? The described way isn't working, because it isn't even deploying without the service account.

Comment: I could suggest the following options:

1. [Create a new project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project).

2. Request an Alpha feature that allows setting a new Service account as Compute Engine Default Service Account. If you have questions regarding an Alpha release or participation in an Alpha program, please reach out to [Sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact/). In this case a Sales team needs to approve it.